# Curious, why can't I retrieve attribute of my own Django Form class?

Tags: django, python-3.x

In a Django project shell(Python 3.5 + Django 1.11), I tried the following statements:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    message = forms.CharField()

print( ContactForm.subject )
```

But I can **not** fetch my `ContactForm.subject` attribute. I got error message:

```
AttributeError: type object 'ContactForm' has no attribute 'subject'
```

Why is it so? Is it caused by some hidden Python language trick?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, forms have a special metaclass that hoist the defined fields into `form.base_fields`.

So if you need to access that field, you can do `ContactForm.base_fields['subject']`, but be aware that modifications to that field **will persist** across requests.

If you need to modify a form field for only a single request, override the form's `__init__`, then modify the form field in `self.fields` (note: *not* `base_fields`), which is a deep copy of the class's `.base_fields`, created within `Form.__init__`.

For example, if you need to do something per-user – to put it in code,

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.CharField(label='Boo')

    def __init__(self, user, **kwargs):
       # We'll assume whatever instantiates this form knows
       # to pass the user object in; for CBVs,
       # that's an override of `get_form_kwargs()`.
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       if user.is_superuser:
           self.fields['field'].label = 'Yay!'
```